# Matlab EDITOR under linux

Tags: linux, matlab, editor

After I connect server via ssh and open matlab

```
$matlab
```

When I enter edit command

```
>>edit
Error: Environment variable EDITOR is not set.
Error using edit (line 66)
Unknown service
```

So I install emacs and follow the tutorial as follow

http://goo.gl/DwgA1v

and it's worked

but when I exit matlab(or disconnect from server)

and re log in (open matlab again) it's will happen again!

I have tried

```
export EDITOR=emacs
```

but it's will happen after I re log in

how to make it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `export EDITOR=emacs` line to the `.profile` file in your home directory, which will be sourced when starting login shells.

Or, add that line to `/etc/profile` to make it apply for all users.

Comment: so I have to do it with other users? or add it and other user can use it too?

Comment: To make it global for all users, add that line to `/etc/profile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says "Environment variable EDITOR is not set!", so you just have to set it by the following code:

```
setenv('EDITOR','emacs')
```

If you want to use another editor just replace it with 'emacs', like:

```
setenv('EDITOR','gedit')
```